# An Euler-Mascheroni-like sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, euler-mascheroni-constant

How does one compute the limit of the sequence:

$$\sum_{k = 0}^{n}\frac{1}{3k+1} - \frac{\ln(n)}{3}$$

I would apreciate a hint.

Comment: It should be trivial to derive the sum from the result in the question that @Lucian referred to above. Accordingly, this question is about to be closed as a duplicate …

Comment: Yes, thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** use a comparison series/integral, by writing $$\frac{\ln n}{3} = \int_{1}^n \frac{dx}{3x}=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \int_{k}^{k+1}\frac{dx}{3x}$$ and
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{3k+1} = \sum_{k=0}^n \int_{k}^{k+1}\frac{dx}{3k+1}$$

**Edit:** is not a straightforward approach -- I was thinking about proving convergence.

Comment: This way it is easy to show that the sequence converges... I don't see how it helps at computing the limit(but of course, I might be missing something - If I am, could I get the complete calculation?)

Comment: Yes, sorry -- not direct from there. (i was thinking about proving convergence, indeed)